# NuGet Package Dependency Auto Upgrade

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a private NuGet package that I'm installing on an existing project.  The project already contains several of the dependencies the private NuGet package requires but at a lower version than what the private package requires.  When I try to install the private package the installation throws an error (no error number)

> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for
>   'ConsoleApp1'.

In the package manager output it is reporting a

> Detected package downgrade

Since the package that it's referencing is a public package on NuGet.org I would expect at a minimum to be prompted to upgrade the dependency during the installation process instead of erroring and rolling back.  I've know packages that are not already included in the project are being installed automatically and can see that in the logs.

I've seen other posting that range from ignoring the warning/error to a pre-build script that does the upgrade (which is not a option for installing new packages)

Can the package manager be instructed to automatically upgrade the existing packages to at least the minimum version the dependency list has defined?

Answer (score 0):

Afraid not.

It's not really a trivial problem to solve - suppose it uses the approach you suggested and your project currently references `packageA` v1.0.0 and `packageB` v1.0.0.

You add a new package with a dependency on `package A` v2.0.0.

It prompts you to upgrade `packageA`from 1.0.0 to 2.0.0 to avoid a downgrade. 
But `package A` 2.0.0 has a new dependency on `packageB`at 2.0.0, which causes a downgrade for you on that package.

Every new upgrade in turn can trigger new upgrades. You can also engineer scenarios where there isn't even a way to upgrade other packages to make it all work. On top of that all of this requires fetching lots of information from your package source.

Since there's not a clear, general way to fix this the tooling leaves you to work out what you want to do yourself.